# How to insert data to different tables

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP to learn about it. I've made a CRUD with relationship, `products/categories`, in the products form i want to put a field named `tags`, separated by comma and insert in another table each tag separated. Examples.

Form products (input:tag)

```
one,two,four
```

tags (table)

```
id | product_id | tag
1       2         one
2       2         two
```

I have no ideia how to do it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on cake associations.
 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Sounds like you have the DB built already, so building your associations should allow for these complex saves to happen. 

The cookbook is a handy resource & how I learned.

Comment: I'll read the link, thank you. But can you show me ane example? I need for urgen.

Comment: It is a LOT to take in, but I live and die by the cookbook for Cake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do here is to modify your data before modyfying your entity. Luckily, there is `Model.beforeMarshal` event, which allows you to do exactly this. A quick and untested example below:

```
//put this in your Table class
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options){
    if(!empty($data["tag_string"]){
        $tags = explode(", ",$data["tag_string"]);
        $tagsData = [];
        foreach($tags as $tag){
            $tagsData[] = ["tag" => $tag];
        }
        $data["tags"] = $tagsData;
    }
}
```

Please note, that I changed `tags` to `tag_string` - it's because `tags`, if you followed CakePHP conventions, will be reserved for your association. Also, by default, your tags will be appended to existing ones, so you need to change your saving strategy with `"saveStrategy" => "replace"` in your association definition.

You need also to retrieve your tag string - to do this, you need to create virtual property in your entity:

```
//put this in your Entity
protected function _getTagString(){
    $tagString = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($this->tags); $i++){
        $tagString .= $this->tags[$i]->tag;
        if($i != count($this->tags) - 1){
            $tagString .= ", ";
        }
    }
    return $tagString;
}
```

With this, you can then retrieve your tag string by calling `$product->tag_string`.

More info can be found in CakePHP cookbook:

[Modyfying request data before building entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities)

[HasMany Association](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#has-many-associations)

[Virtual Properties](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties)

Comment: Thank you, i was reading the doc and i got it, but your thread is more accurate.